# Split and retain substring in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Is there a way to split on a certain character then keep that character in the array.

For example, `"hello ??? world"` split on `???` would give `["hello ", "???", "world"]`.

This is different from the JavaScript split method which gives `[ "hello ", " world" ]` (which doesn't retain the ???  in the substring).

This is what I've got so far with some test cases, but I'm not sure what to use to keep the substring.

```
var splitter = (str) => {
  return str.split('???');
}

// Tests
console.log(splitter("this is some text ???") === ["this is some text ", "???"])
console.log(splitter("this is ??? text???") === ["this is ", "???", " text", "???"])
console.log(splitter("this is some text") === ["this is some text"])
console.log(splitter("(???)") === ["(", "???", ")"])
console.log(splitter("   ") === ["   "])
console.log(splitter(" ??? ") === [" ", "???", " "])
console.log(splitter("??????") === ["???", "???"])
console.log(splitter("?????????") === ["???", "???", "???"])
console.log(splitter("(??????") === ["(", "???", "???"])
```

Comment: Fixed the  3rd-from-last line. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `split` accepts a regular expression, and captured groups inside the match will be included in the output, you can just `split` on a captured group of `\?\?\?`. (Because `?` is a special character in a regular expression, to indicate a literal `?`, you must escape it first, via `\`.)

Then, to filter out empty matches, use `.filter(Boolean)` on the result:

```
var splitter = (str) => (
    str.split(/(\?\?\?)/)
      .filter(Boolean)
);
```

Also note that since arrays are objects, a newly created array will never be `===` to another, eg `<anything> === ['anything else']` will *always* be `false` - to compare values, stringify the arrays first, via `stringify` or `join`.

```js
    var splitter = (str) => {
      return JSON.stringify(
        str.split(/(\?\?\?)/)
          .filter(Boolean)
        );
    }

// Tests
console.log(splitter("this is some text ???") === JSON.stringify(["this is some text ", "???"]))
console.log(splitter("this is ??? text???") === JSON.stringify(["this is ", "???", " text", "???"]))
console.log(splitter("this is some text") === JSON.stringify(["this is some text"]))
console.log(splitter("(???)") === JSON.stringify(["(", "???", ")"]))
console.log(splitter("   ") === JSON.stringify(["   "]))
console.log(splitter(" ??? ") === JSON.stringify([" ", "???", " "]))
console.log(splitter("??????") === JSON.stringify(["???", "???"]))
console.log(splitter("?????????") === JSON.stringify(["???", "???", "???"]))
console.log(splitter("(??????") === JSON.stringify(["(", "???", "???"]))
```